# Selector for Swift method containing one named parameter

Tags: swift, xamarin

I have the following Swift method:

```
@objc public func theme(withIdentifier identifier: String?) -> Theme? {
    [...]
}
```

I wish to create a Xamarin binding to it but I'm having trouble deciding the correct selector. I've tried:

```
[Export("theme:")]
Theme Theme(string identifier);
```

But I get:

> -[TKThemeManager theme:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000025b4680

And I've tried:

```
[Export("theme:withIdentifier:")]
Theme Theme(string identifier);
```

Which gives:

> The registrar found a signature mismatch in the method
>   'MyApp.Mac.ThemeKit.ThemeManager.Theme' - the selector
>   'theme:withIdentifier:' indicates the method takes 2 parameters, while
>   the managed method has 1 parameters.

Which is true of course.

What is the correct selector for calling this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct selector is

```
themeWithIdentifier:
```

Comment: And see http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors_2 for the rules about how a selector is formed.